# Sending snort alerts to the elk stack in Security Onion

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, elastic-stack, snort, elk

I'm new to the ELK stack, but I want to send my alerts from snort to it in security onion.  I have 2 questions:

1. In security onion is logstash preconfigured to receive snort alerts or do I need to define that configuration?
2. Do I need to send my alerts to logstash, or can it just be sent to elasticsearch?

Thanks!